# spring-integration: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'errorChannel'

Tags: spring-integration

I have chain of process like this

```
 <int:chain input-channel="filesInChannel" output-channel="outJsonMap" >
    <int:transformer id="confCombiner" ref="serviceCombiner" method="addConfig"/>
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="fileMatchConf" expression="payload.get('matchConf')"/>
        <int:header name="fileName" expression="payload.get('file').getName()"/>
        <int:header name="fileTimeProp" expression="payload.get('fileTimeProp')"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:transformer expression="payload.get('file')"/>
    <int:transformer id="sasTransformer" ref="serviceTransformer" method="process" />
</int:chain>
```

The final process is converting sas file to pojo. This app work for large amount of file, and for test we use -+1000 file. I found weird behavior of my app. Sometimes the app smoothly process all files but sometimes the app suddenly stopped and got exception like this :

```
2016-06-29 09:47:05 44591 [Thread-1014] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2016-06-29 09:47:05 44592 [executor-86] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
Exception in thread "executor-86" Exception in thread "Thread-1014" 2016-06-29 09:47:05 44112 [executor-31] DEBUG com.epam.parso.impl.SasFileParser  - Column format: $
2016-06-29 09:47:05 44592 [executor-31] DEBUG com.epam.parso.impl.SasFileParser  - Subheader process function name: FORMAT_AND_LABEL_SUBHEADER_INDEX
org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'errorChannel' in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with na  me 'errorChannel': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a b  ean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!) at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:112)
at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:45)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler.resolveErrorChannel(MessagePublishingErrorHandler.java:117)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler.handleError(MessagePublishingErrorHandler.java:80)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-06-29 09:47:05 44592 [executor-31]DEBUG com.epam.parso.impl.SasFileParser  - Column format: $at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'errorChannel': Single  ton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in   a destroy method implementation!)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:2  16)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2016-06-29 09:47:05 44593 [executor-31] DEBUG com.epam.parso.impl.SasFileParser  - Subheader process function name:
```

From that exception, `SasFileParser` was invoked within `serviceTransformer` in method "process".

This is implementation of transformer code:

```
 public JobMessage process(@Payload File file, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws IOException {

        JobMessage jobMessage = new JobMessage();
        logger.info("headers:"+headers.get("fileMatchConf"));
        FileInputStream is = null;
        String timestamp_datameerJob = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

        try {

            // create message parser same like in SuccessUnwrapper
            Adr adr = (Adr) headers.get("fileMatchConf");

            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            com.epam.parso.SasFileReader sasFileReader = new SasFileReaderImpl(is);

            String fileName = file.getName();
            String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            String dirCode = adr.getDirectoryCode();
            String scenario = "";
            String tableName = "";
            String loadType = adr.getLoadType();

            Path fileP = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
            BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(fileP, BasicFileAttributes.class);
            Long timestamp_createdDate = attr.creationTime().toMillis();



            // get tableName
            // check load_type (M,R) or (H,S)
            if(loadType.toLowerCase().equals("m") || loadType.toLowerCase().equals("r")){
                tableName = adr.getTargetTableName();
            } else{
                // check which scenario used
                scenario = FileUtil.filePatternScenarioSelector(fileName);
                logger.info("[SCENARIO] " + scenario);

                if(scenario.equals("scenario2")){
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                    String createdDate = formatter.format(new java.util.Date (timestamp_createdDate));
                    String mainFileName = fileName.split("\\.")[0];

                    tableName = mainFileName+"_"+createdDate+"_"+ dirCode;
                } else if(scenario.equals("scenario1_3")){
                    tableName = NamingFunctionMapUtil.getInstance().getScenarioOneThree(fileName, dirCode).get("appendDirID");
                }
            }


            // import job
            ImportConstructor imc = new ImportConstructor(sasFileReader.getColumns(), fileName);
            imc.constructImport(absolutePath, dirCode, timestamp_datameerJob); // real environment
            ImportJob importJob = imc.getImportJob();
            logger.info("[IMPORT_JOB] " + importJob);


            // workbook job
            WorkBookConstructor wrk = new WorkBookConstructor(importJob, fileName);
            wrk.constructWorkbook(dirCode, timestamp_datameerJob);
            id.lsa.scb.mappers.workbook.WorkBook workBook = wrk.getWorkBook();
            logger.info("[WORKBOOK_JOB]" + workBook);


            // export job
            ExportConstructor exc = new ExportConstructor(sasFileReader.getColumns(), fileName, workBook);
            exc.constructExportJob(adr.getTargetDatabase(), tableName, dirCode, timestamp_datameerJob);
            id.lsa.scb.mappers.exportjob.ExportJob exportJob = exc.getExportJob();
            logger.info("[EXPORT_JOB]" + exportJob);

            jobMessage.setFileName(fileName);
            jobMessage.setTableName(tableName);
            jobMessage.setCountryCode(adr.getCountryCode());
            jobMessage.setDirectoryPath(adr.getDirectoryPath());
            jobMessage.setDirectoryCode(adr.getDirectoryCode());
            jobMessage.setFilePatternUsed(adr.getFilePattern());
            jobMessage.setTargetDatabase(adr.getTargetDatabase());
            jobMessage.setLoadType(adr.getLoadType());

            jobMessage.setImportJob(importJob);
            jobMessage.setWorkBook(workBook);
            jobMessage.setExportJob(exportJob);

            jobMessage.setFileCredentials(constructCredentialFiles(file));


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch (IOException ioex){
            String message= ioex.getMessage();
            logger.error(message);
            logToDb(headers,"failed","file-convert",message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            String message= ex.getMessage();
            logToDb(headers,"failed","file-convert",message);
        } finally {
            if(is!=null) {
                is.close();
                is=null;
            }
        }
```

In "confCombiner" i also get attribute of sas file like this:

```
Path fileP = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        BasicFileAttributes attr = null;
        try {
            attr = Files.readAttributes(fileP, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Long fileCreatedTime = attr.creationTime().toMillis();
        Long fileModifiedTime = attr.lastModifiedTime().toMillis();
```

Anyone has experience with that exception? How to deal with that? Or any advice of other pattern to accommodate that flow? Or  At least to know the source of the problem of it. It's looks very weird for me because i use same example of files for each running test. I need the app keep running to process next file if this exception happen. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
com.epam.parso.impl.SasFileParser  - Column format: $
    2016-06-29 09:47:05 44592 [executor-31] DEBUG com.epam.parso.impl.SasFileParser  - Subheader process function name: FORMAT_AND_LABEL_SUBHEADER_INDEX
```

This is your code and your own problem. I'm afraid that we can't help you here without any other background on the matter.

The problem like:

```
Error creating bean with name 'errorChannel': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
```

says that you have some unexpected `destroy()` call which causes on-the-fly processes to finish bad way.

So, please, reconsider how you deal with the flow or the entire application at all. Especially destroy or exit part.

Comment: Thanks Artem for the advice, Actually the SasFileParser is from third party lib. If i define that class as spring bean, Whether this could be the solution?. at least can catch the exception.  please check the update question i attach the corresponding code. Thank you very much.

Comment: I need the app keep running to process next file when that exception happen. Thanks